# Using pip in virtualenv with a space in the filepath?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm working on OSX 10.13.3 with Python 2.7 installed. I want to make a virtualenv with Python 3 and Django 2.0. I have made a virtualenv as follows:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 .venv
```

It says `Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.`.

Then I enter the virtualenv with:

```
source .venv/bin/activate
```

But when I try `pip install Django` I get:

```
-bash: /Users/me/Dropbox (Personal)/Projects/landapp/.venv/bin/pip: "/Users/me/Dropbox: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I think this might be something to do with having a space in the path?

I need to use Dropbox for both business and personal, and I'd rather not rename the folders, as I suspect it'll cause other problems. Is there any way around this?

Comment: You can try to symlink "Dropbox ..." to something without spaces.

Comment: @khachik thanks - symlinking "Dropbox" to "Dropbox (Personal)" and "Dropbox (Personal)" to "Dropbox_Personal" has done the trick. :)